# I am having a Quick Sort error with infinite re cursion

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, quicksort

I am having problems with my quicksort function constantly re cursing the best of three function. I dont know why it is doing that and i need help. I am trying to practice this for my coding class next semester and this is one of the assignments from last year that my friend had and im lost when it comes to this error
This is my quicksort function:

```
def quick_sort ( alist, function  ):
    if len(alist) <= 1:
        return alist + []
    pivot, index = function(alist)
    #print("Pivot:",pivot)

    left = []
    right = []


    for value in range(len(alist)):
        if value == index:
            continue
        if alist[value] <= pivot:
            left.append(alist[value])
        else:
            right.append(alist[value])
    print("left:", left)
    print("right:", right)

    sortedleft = quick_sort( left, function )
    print("sortedleft", sortedleft)
    sortedright = quick_sort( right, function )
    print("sortedright", sortedright)

    completeList = sortedleft + [pivot] + sortedright

    return completeList

#main

alist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

x = quick_sort(alist, best_of_three)
print(x)
```

this is my best of three function:

```
def best_of_three( bNlist, nine = False ):
   rightindex = 2
   middleindex = 1
   if nine == False:

      left = blist[0]
      rightindex = int(len(blist) - 1)
      rightvalue = int(blist[rightindex])
      middleindex = int((len(blist) - 1)/2)
      middlevalue = int(blist[middleindex])
      bNlist.append(left)
      bNlist.append(middlevalue)
      bNlist.append(rightvalue)
      BN = bNlist
      print("Values:",BN)
   left = bNlist[0]
   middle = bNlist[1]
   right = bNlist[2]

   if left <= middle <= right:
      return middle , middleindex
   elif left >= middle >= right:
      return middle, middleindex
   elif middle <= right <= left:
      return right, rightindex
   elif middle >= right >= left:
      return right, rightindex
   else:
      return left, 0

#main
bNlist = []
print('Best of Three')
blist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55]
print("")
print( "List:   [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55]" )
x, index = best_of_three(bNlist)

print("Pivot: ",x)
print("----------------------------")
```

i really dont know why it keeps infinitely re cursing,

There is also a third function called ninther

```
def ninther( bNlist ):


   stepsize = int(len(blist) / 9)
   left = 0
   middle = left + 2
   right = left + 2 * stepsize

   blist[left]
   blist[middle]
   blist[right]
   leftvalue = blist[left]
   rightvalue = blist[right]
   middlevalue = blist[middle]

   left2 = right + stepsize
   middle2 = left2 + 2
   right2 = left2 + 2 * stepsize

   blist[left2]
   blist[middle2]
   blist[right2]
   left2value = blist[left2]
   middle2value = blist[middle2]
   right2value = blist[right2]

   left3 = right2 + stepsize
   middle3 = left3 + 2
   right3 = left3 + 2 * stepsize

   blist[left3]
   blist[middle3]
   blist[right3]
   left3value = blist[left3]
   middle3value = blist[middle3]
   right3value = blist[right3]

   bN3list = []
   bN2list = []
   bNlist = []

   bNlist.append(leftvalue)
   bNlist.append(middlevalue)
   bNlist.append(rightvalue)

   bN2list.append(left2value)
   bN2list.append(middle2value)
   bN2list.append(right2value)

   bN3list.append(left3value)
   bN3list.append(middle3value)
   bN3list.append(right3value)

   BN3 = bN3list
   BN2 = bN2list
   BN = bNlist
   print("Ninter ")
   print("Group 1:", BN)
   print("Group 2:", BN2)
   print("Group 3:", BN3)

   x = best_of_three(bNlist, True)[0]
   c = best_of_three(bN2list, True)[0]
   d = best_of_three(bN3list, True)[0]
   print("Median 1:", x)
   print("Median 2:", c)
   print("Median 3:", d)

   bN4list = [x,c,d]
   print("All Medians:", bN4list)

   z = best_of_three(bN4list, True)


   return z[0], z[1]

#main

blist = [2, 6, 9, 7, 13, 4, 3, 5, 11, 1, 20, 12, 8, 10, 32, 16, 14, 17, 21, 46]
Y = ninther(blist)

print("Pivot", Y)
print("----------------------------")
```

i have looked everywhere in it and i cant figure out where the problem is when calling best of three

Answer (score 0):

Summary: The main error causing infinite recursion is that you don't deal with the case where best_of_three receives a length 2 list. A secondary error is that `best_of_three` modifies the list you send to it. If I correct these two errors, as below, your code works.

The details: `best_of_three([1, 2])` returns `(2, 3)`, implying a pivot value of 2 at the third index, which is wrong. This would give a left list of `[1, 2]`, which then causes exactly the same behavior at the next recursive `quick_sort(left, function)` call.

More generally, the problem is that the very idea of choosing the best index out of three possible values is impossible for a length 2 list, and you haven't chosen how to deal with that special case.

If I add this special case code to `best_of_three`, it deals with the length 2 case:

```
if len(bNlist) == 2:
    return bNlist[1], 1
```

The function `best_of_three` also *modifies* `bNlist`. I have no idea why you have the lines of the form `bNlist.append(left)` in that function.

```
L = [15, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17]
best_of_three(L)
print(L)  # prints [15, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 54, 17, 55]
```

I removed the `append` lines, since having `best_of_three` modify `bNlist` is unlikely to be what you want, and I have no idea why those lines are there. However, you should ask yourself why they are there to begin with. There might be some reason I don't know about. When I do that, there are a couple of quantities you compute that are never used, so I remove the lines that compute those also.

Then I notice you have the code

```
rightindex = 2
middleindex = 1
if nine == False:
    rightindex = int(len(blist) - 1)
    middleindex = int((len(blist) - 1)/2)
left = bNlist[0]
middle = bNlist[1]
right = bNlist[2]
```

This doesn't seem to make any sense, since you set `rightindex` and `middleindex` to other values, but then you still access values using the old indices (2 and 1 respectively). So I removed the `if nine == False` block. Again, ask yourself why you had this code to begin with, maybe there's some other way you should modify this to account for something I don't know about.

The result is the following for `best_of_three`:

```
def best_of_three(bNlist):
    print(bNlist)
    if len(bNlist) == 2:
        return bNlist[1], 1
    rightindex = 2
    middleindex = 1
    left = bNlist[0]
    middle = bNlist[1]
    right = bNlist[2]

    if left <= middle <= right:
        return middle , middleindex
    elif left >= middle >= right:
        return middle, middleindex
    elif middle <= right <= left:
        return right, rightindex
    elif middle >= right >= left:
        return right, rightindex
    else:
        return left, 0
```

If I use this, your code does not recurse infinitely, and it sorts.

I don't know why you mentioned `ninther` at all, since it seems to have nothing to do with your question. You should probably edit it to remove that code.